# 404 in custom post type feed with mistake permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, 404-error, feed

I have a wordpress site that uses this custom post type : "movie" in theme.

I changed permalinks to "%postname%.

Every things is ok but google gives a toll 404 error for any custom post type articles.

I checked the errors in webmaster tools and found every article in custom post type has this link:
"http://example.com/movie/article-name/feed/"
that is not exist (404 error).

The issue is here:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="someTitle" href="http://example.com/movie/article-name/feed/">
```

But by changing that address to this:
"http://example.com/article-name/feed"
it has ok.

I changed permalinks after installing new theme.

Please help me.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue - we are investigating why the feed link is not working

Answer (score -1):

Hello You needs to read document of following site:

https://wordimpress.com/solve-wordpress-custom-post-type-404-error-issues/

Comment: link only answer are not valid answers.... answer should be self contained with external link just adding to the answer, not being the answer itself

Comment: This isn't my issue's solution.
@tarun-modi